# MYSQL Select first rows after specified

Tags: mysql, rows

I have  table with positions of car (from gps tracker)  and I want to select positions of start  and end of drive. So I should select first row where speed >0 and last where speed was >0 with specific date (day). How can I do this?

For example I have table with values:

```
+------+-------+---------------------+
| id   | speed | date                |
+------+-------+---------------------+
|    1 |     0 | 2015-02-03 10:00:00 |
|    2 |    10 | 2015-02-03 10:00:10 |
|    3 |    50 | 2015-02-03 10:00:20 |
|    4 |   100 | 2015-02-03 10:00:30 |
|    5 |    50 | 2015-02-03 10:01:00 |
|    6 |     0 | 2015-02-03 10:01:10 |
|    7 |    10 | 2015-02-03 12:00:10 |
|    8 |    50 | 2015-02-03 12:00:20 |
|    9 |   100 | 2015-02-03 12:00:30 |
|   10 |    50 | 2015-02-03 12:01:00 |
|   11 |     0 | 2015-02-03 12:01:10 |
+------+-------+---------------------+
```

And I need to select records with ids: 2,5,7,11

**EDIT**

This is the full  list of columns : id (identity), car_id,altitude,latitude,longitude,speed,date

I need to calculate each track distance. (one car may drive many times in 1 day - it can drive from 6 am to 10 am, then stop on parking from 10 am to 1 pm and then  again drive from 1pm to 5 pm.)  So first I need  to "detect" start and stop of driving (car also send data to database when it keeps on parking (speed=0) ),then  calculate distance using something like this [distance calculations in mysql queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986556/distance-calculations-in-mysql-queries)

This is the database from http://www.traccar.org/ project.

Comment: I don't understand the question can you try to be more specific? What is your desired output? Can you show an example of what you have tried so far?

Comment: What query you tried?

Answer (score 0):

If your ID grows over time then you can use two sub queries (without having to use `HAVING`):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE id IN (
   SELECT MIN(id) FROM mytable
   WHERE speed > 0
   GROUP BY DAY(date)
)
OR id IN (
   SELECT MAX(id) FROM mytable
   WHERE speed > 0
   GROUP BY DAY(date)
)
```

The first sub query selects the MIN(id) per day, the second the MAX(id) per day. In both cases only rows with speed > 0 are returned. This should get you the first ID for each day with speed > 0 and the last one.

If you do not want to rely on the IDs being sorted by date, you have to use `HAVING date = MIN(date)` instead of `MIN(id)` (the same goes for `MAX(id)`).

Of course, `date` is a reserved keyword, so you probably have to escape it.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to add a column like `car_id` which relates each record to a car:

```
+------+--------+-------+---------------------+
| id   | car_id | speed | date                |
+------+--------+-------+---------------------+
|    1 |      1 |     0 | 2015-02-03 10:00:00 |
|    2 |      1 |    10 | 2015-02-03 10:00:10 |
|    3 |      1 |    50 | 2015-02-03 10:00:20 |
|    4 |      1 |   100 | 2015-02-03 10:00:30 |
|    5 |      1 |    50 | 2015-02-03 10:01:00 |
|    6 |      2 |     0 | 2015-02-03 10:01:10 |
|    7 |      2 |    10 | 2015-02-03 12:00:10 |
|    8 |      2 |    50 | 2015-02-03 12:00:20 |
|    9 |      2 |   100 | 2015-02-03 12:00:30 |
|   10 |      2 |    50 | 2015-02-03 12:01:00 |
|   11 |      3 |     0 | 2015-02-03 12:01:10 |
+------+--------+-------+---------------------+
```

Then you could get the desired rows by using a query like:

```
SELECT MAX(id) id, car_id, MAX(`date`) `date` FROM <table> 
WHERE speed > 0 
GROUP BY car_id 
ORDER BY speed ASC;

+------+--------+---------------------+
| id   | car_id | date                |
+------+--------+---------------------+
|    5 |      1 | 2015-02-03 10:01:00 |
|   10 |      2 | 2015-02-03 12:01:00 |
+------+--------+---------------------+
```